Auth0 redirects to LinkedIn but LinkedIn is failing to load
I've created a LinkedIn App through the LinkedIn developer portal to connect my SSO provider Auth0 to LinkedIn. This will help users of my Custom App to sign in directly using their LinkedIn profiles. However, even though I have followed all the requisite steps to create this connection, there is some persistent issue that blocks user access to LinkedIn. This is working smoothly for Google and Twitter/X and I would love to also offer LinkedIn as a sign-in option. What's the way forward?
enter image description here
Expected behaviour: LinkedIn should load, asking users to authorise my app to connect with their LinkedIn profile
What I've tried: there's no clear error message so there's no specific fix I could think of. I've deleted and recreated the Auth0-LinkedIn connection a few times, but the issue persists
I wrote to LinkedIn but they asked me to post this issue here, which I am very confused by.

In the 'products' section of your app, request access for 'Sign In with LinkedIn using OpenID Connect'.
